# How to use OAuth in JWT authorization mechanism

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

At my project I am using JWT to authorize users, but it works only with my own authorization, I need to make possible authorize using Google account, so I need to add Google OAuth 2 authorization, but as i understand it stores token in cookies but i need to make my application stateless since im using JWT, also i need to make tokens from google "valid". I have read this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt) but as I understood it shows how to make your own OAuth authorization, but I dont need to create new mechanism, i just need to add  authorization via Google using JWT. So how to make OAuth authorization via JWT  ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore the auth0 service (auth0.com) - they might provide the functionality you require as a free service, unless there are constraints which mean you could not use such services.